# ffmpeg get stream from card cannot find capture pin

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, video-capture

I am trying to capture video from card using ffmpeg, but I cant get a Capture pin. 
I write a following command:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

And get the information:

```
[dshow @ 0000000002b1f680] DirectShow video devices
[dshow @ 0000000002b1f680]  "MB86H55-REB PCI Capture(0)"
[dshow @ 0000000002b1f680]  "MB86H55-REB PCI Capture(1)"
[dshow @ 0000000002b1f680]  "MB86H55-REB PCI Capture(2)"
[dshow @ 0000000002b1f680]  "MB86H55-REB PCI Capture(3)"
[dshow @ 0000000002b1f680]  "MB86H55-REB PCI Capture(4)"
[dshow @ 0000000002b1f680]  "MB86H55-REB PCI Capture(5)"
[dshow @ 0000000002b1f680]  "MB86H55-REB PCI Capture(6)"
[dshow @ 0000000002b1f680]  "MB86H55-REB PCI Capture(7)"
[dshow @ 0000000002b1f680] DirectShow audio devices
```

So I have got a device which support DirectShow. And after this I'd like to check my support resolution and parameters for this cards.

```
ffmpeg -list_options true -f dshow -i video="MB86H55-REB PCI Capture(0)"
```

And find me only stream out and none parameters for this card.

```
[dshow @ 0000000002b7f680] DirectShow video device options
[dshow @ 0000000002b7f680]  Pin "Stream Out"
[dshow @ 0000000002b7f680]  Pin "Virtual Stream Out"
```

And I cannot get any stream via ffmpeg or even I cannot show preview. 
Has got any idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: I guess you tried to list the options for every one of the devices found ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to list the options for one input from a device. I've got a card with multiple hdmi inputs and I want to stream from each inputs, but I can't get stream even from one.

Comment: Looks like a driver issue, the pins are not properly marked or something more serious.

Comment: What do you mean that: "the pins are not properly marked" ? I have got program from this card, which called HDPreview and it captured the video. But I want get a stream and create preview in live, but the program only can capture a video and save to a file. I cannot get a preview from it. But card is working and I don't think so, that it is a problem in drivers. Have you another solution?

Comment: Pins are normally "marked" to indicate they are of certain category. Applications use that to identify proper pins they need. This card might be shipped with an application that identifies the pins using alternate assumptions (by name, index etc). This is why this app can be operational while third party well built apps still have troubles to interface to the device. All together this means that drivers have compatibility issues causing third party apps to fail to work with the card. Your last comment only confirms that this is the cause.

Comment: So I understand that from your replay that I am not able to get any stream from this card with my code ? In your opinion what should I do to get this stream ? I don't have any idea more and I must write an application to get capture from this card and show a preview in C#. I really stack

Comment: But there is no "your code" on the question. You're referring to FFmpeg, and if FFmpeg is unable to interface to that card, it does not mean you cannot. Even using FFmpeg by patching its source code.

Comment: But I tried also DirectShow in C# and is not working also. And this is my question, Have you got any idea how solve this problem, any other libraries to make it? I have got dll file with my cards,  which was creating a movie and it pretty works well, but it was saving stream to a file. And in my project I must have real live view and I am wondering about to get the stream when is saving to a file but how do this and if is even possible ? Any solution?

Comment: what types do those pins advertise?